# GitLab: Can't send email via SMTP

Tags: email, azure, smtp, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm using GitLab Community Edition 8.8.5 68cd138 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Trusty Tahr) in a VM in Azure.

I'd been unsuccessful in configuring Postfix so I tried to use SMTP with my SendGrid account.  Previously I'd been successful but not this time. When a new user creates an account for themselves I expect to see that person receive an email, but they never receive the email.

So I looked at /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production and saw:

```
Started POST "/users" for 73.181.210.158 at 2016-06-18 03:45:55 +0000
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "new_user"=>{"name"=>"mike", "username"=>"mike", "email"=>"michpa@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 8059c988-62ef-4d53-adac-966c6f5e3dea) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "DeviseMailer", "confirmation_instructions", "deliver_now", gid://gitlab/User/5, "BzAurLoc2kgybwF1U1Aj", {}
Redirected to http://gitlab1.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/users/almost_there
Completed 302 Found in 943ms (ActiveRecord: 52.7ms)
Started GET "/users/almost_there" for 73.181.210.158 at 2016-06-18 03:45:56 +0000
Processing by ConfirmationsController#almost_there as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 32.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

The relevant line appears to be *Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 8059blahblah) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "confirmation_instructions", "deliver_now", **gid://gitlab/User/5*** - this seems to indicate that GitLab is attempting to send the email.

The [GitLab documentation on logs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/logs.html#sidekiq.log) says that "GitLab uses background jobs for processing tasks which can take a long time. All information about processing these jobs are written down to this file." so it makes sense that GitLab is handing this off to SideKiq.

Looking at /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq.log I see:

```
mike@GitLab1:/etc$ sudo less /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq.log
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18949 2016-06-18T03:45:56.189Z 1201 TID-94irw WARN: {"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","queue":"mailers","args":[{"job_class":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","job_id":"8059c988-62ef-4d53-adac-966c6f5e3dea","queue_name":"mailers","arguments":["DeviseMailer","confirmation_instructions","deliver_now",{"_aj_globalid":"gid://gitlab/User/5"},"BzAurLoc2kgybwF1U1Aj",{"_aj_symbol_keys":[]}],"locale":"en"}],"retry":true,"jid":"a921cf1158df78df6bf7ee2b","created_at":1466221556.1722102,"enqueued_at":1466221556.1723359,"error_message":"Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find User with 'id'=5","error_class":"ActiveJob::DeserializationError","failed_at":1466221556.184139,"retry_count":0}
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18957 2016-06-18T03:45:56.189Z 1201 TID-94irw WARN: ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find User with 'id'=5
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18967 2016-06-18T03:45:56.189Z 1201 TID-94irw WARN: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:324:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18968 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:444:in `find_one'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18968 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:423:in `find_with_ids'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18969 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18969 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18970 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:131:in `find'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18970 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/globalid-0.3.6/lib/global_id/locator.rb:132:in `locate'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18971 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/globalid-0.3.6/lib/global_id/locator.rb:158:in `block in locate'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18972 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:33:in `block in unscoped'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18972 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:302:in `scoping'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18973 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:33:in `unscoped'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18973 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/globalid-0.3.6/lib/global_id/locator.rb:158:in `locate'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18974 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/globalid-0.3.6/lib/global_id/locator.rb:17:in `locate'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18974 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:97:in `deserialize_global_id'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18975 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:83:in `deserialize_argument'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18975 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:40:in `block in deserialize'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18977 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:40:in `map'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18978 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:40:in `deserialize'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18978 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/core.rb:90:in `deserialize_arguments'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18979 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/core.rb:80:in `deserialize_arguments_if_needed'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18979 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/execution.rb:30:in `perform_now'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18980 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18980 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activejob-4.2.6/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb:42:in `perform'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18980 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:152:in `execute_job'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18981 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in process'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18981 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18982 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/memory_killer.rb:17:in `call'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18983 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18983 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18984 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18984 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18984 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18985 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18985 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in `with_context'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18986 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18988 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18989 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `call'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18989 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18990 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:129:in `block in process'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18990 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:168:in `stats'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18990 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in `process'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18991 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:80:in `process_one'
2016-06-18_03:45:56.18991 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
```

I think that the most relevant part is the end of that first line:
*ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: **Couldn't find User with 'id'=5***

So it appears that GitLab is unable to send the email because the new user that it just created can't be found (via the ID number of 5).

Has anyone else encountered this and/or fixed this?

Alternately, does anyone have any advice on what to try next?

EDIT: This issue appears to be similar to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17250

Comment: did you get email issue solved? I am also trying to send emails using the same setup.

Comment: I've still got an item on my TODO list that says "Iron out GitLab email issues", so no :)
Personally I was hoping to use one of the new GitLab images for Azure and maybe that would work instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is now with [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#deliver-emails-using-microsoft-graph-api-with-client-credentials-flow) (October 2022) another option:

> ### Deliver emails using Microsoft Graph API with client credentials flow
>
> If you’ve enabled security defaults in Azure AD,
> [legacy authentication protocols for SMTP are blocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults#block-legacy-authentication-protocols).
>
> You can now configure your GitLab instance to deliver emails using
> [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail)
> with [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).
>
> See [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8259), [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/microsoft_graph_mailer.html) and [Merge Request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/97372).